# Data updation in DB in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have view where users enters about their Profile details like username , firstname , lastname etc. The above mentioned happens as soon as they register and directed to the view. The users are redirected to use the rest of the features only if they give their profile details. The users can also update the profile details in future.

Here when the user wants to update the details later in the profile detail update page , i have already filled the page with the details given after registration. The issue here is when i submit the form its says the username is already taken. Here is the code of the view

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Name</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo \Auth::user()->username;?>">

@if ($errors->has('username'))
<span class="help-block">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
</div>
```

But i am not creating a new row in the DB but i am updating the existing column and still it throws the same error. Here is my controller code.

```
`public function prof_details(Request $request)
{
    $post = $request->all();

    $val=\Validator::make($request->all(),

    [
       'firstname' =>    'required',
       'lastname' =>     'required',
       'username' =>     'required | unique:users',
       'phone'=>         'required',
       'nationality' =>  'required',
       'dobmonth' =>     'required',
       'dobyear' =>      'required',
       'dobday' =>       'required',
       'bio' =>          'required',
       'topics' =>       'required',

    ]


    );

if ($val ->fails()) 
{

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($val->errors());

}`

else
{


    $data = array(

       'firstname' => $post['firstname'] ,
       'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
       'username' => $post['username'],
       'phone' => $post['phone'],
       'nationality' => $nationality,
       'dobmonth' => $post['dobmonth'],
       'dobyear' => $post['dobyear'],
       'dobday' => $post['dobday'],
       'topics' => implode(',', $post['topics']),
       'bio'    => $post['bio'],


        );

    $updatedata = DB::table('users')->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)
    ->update($data);

    if ($updatedata>0) {


        return redirect('home');
}
else
{
    return "something Went wrong";
}
```

Is this a right way to do it ? or which one is the right way for this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`'username' =>     'required | unique:users,id,'.\Auth::user()->id,`

Insert the id as the third parameter so that it'll avoid checking upon the data that you are trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

The username input is in the form and for each update you make the username is updated , when in your your code is : **'username' =>     'required | unique:users'** .

In this case "username is already taken" error with show if no text is changed in the username input.

Perhaps you should leave only the general data in the update form. For username change you can create a different view with only username input.